# Uso de AsyncTask me trae problemas con Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, android, hilos, asynctask

Tengo un problema con el uso de hilos en android.

Es muy sencillo, tengo en la pantalla una tabla con botones. Intento que, aleatoriamente, uno cambie de color y tras medio segundo, vuelva al color original, para que al momento se vuelva a encender otro.

La parte que me da problemas es con los hilos:

```
class colores extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    private AppCompatActivity actividad;
    private int aleatorio;

    public colores(AppCompatActivity cx){
        this.actividad=cx;
    }

    public void generarAleatorio(){
        aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * (28 - 0) + 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    generarAleatorio();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            boton[aleatorio].setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            boton[aleatorio].setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return null;
    }
}
```

El código anterior, estaría dentro de otra clase 
("boton", es un array de `Button` y el 28 de aleatorio es por el tamaño de dicho array).

El problema que tengo es que me cambia de color sólo a amarillo, luego para medio segundo y pone otro botón en amarillo, sin volver a poner el último cambiado en blanco. El resultado es que todos acaban en amarillo sin pasar por el blanco.

¿Puede ser problema del `Thread.sleep()` en conjunción con los dos `runOnUiThread()`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No te recomiendo que lances un Thread dentro de doInBackground de un Asynktask y dentro de ese Thread más Threads.

> Es muy sencillo, tengo en la pantalla una tabla con botones. Intento
>   que, aleatoriamente, uno cambie de color y tras medio segundo, vuelva
>   al color original, para que al momento se vuelva a encender otro.

Para esto intenta implementar una solución parecida a esta:

No uses tu Asynktask para esto y dónde llamabas tu Asynktask, llama directamente al método que pinte el botón de amarillo.

```
public void paintYellow(Button button){
    //...
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            paintWhite(Button button);
        }
    }, 500); // 500 ms = 0.5 segundos
}

private void paintWhite(Button button){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });
}
```